# Custom Button/EditBox are invisible?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-view

I get this error when viewing my app.
"The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:
Path.isConvex is not supported. (Ignore for this session)"
see picture of error: 
[image]

Here are the widgets in the activity_main.xml

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/RoomEditText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_go"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minWidth="256dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/RoomEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ImageButton1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/editbox_round"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLength="15"
    android:minHeight="32dp"
    android:minWidth="256dp" />
```

Here are the drawables:

**button_go.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#cc1a22"
        android:startColor="#550200" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp" >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

**editbox_round.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000"
    />
    <corners 
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    />
</shape>
```

I'm not exactly sure why they are showing up invisible. If someone would be as kind to show me what exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 17):

You get "Path.isConvex is not supported" error because you get a radius value for each corner separately. You must use

```
<corners android:radius="10dip" />
```

instead of

```
<corners 
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure, but sometimes preview is not so accurate and may not be available. Try run on actual device or emulator to see if it visible or not.